# "Clear" button in shiny app is not clearing plots

Tags: r, shiny

I recently started to study shiny. With the following code, when `shinyApp(ui, server)` is called and the shiny app opens, button 1 and 5 work, but I can't get the "Clear" button to clear the plots. How do I correctly implement the "Clear" button?

```
library(MASS)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Machine Learning"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel("Tasks"),
     mainPanel("Regression")
   ),
   actionButton("btn1","1"),
   actionButton("btn2","2"),
   actionButton("btn3","3"),
   actionButton("btn4","4"),
   actionButton("btn5","5"),
   actionButton("reset","Clear"),
   plotOutput("task1"),
   plotOutput("task5")
 )
 server <- function(input, output){
   task1<-reactiveValues(data=NULL)
   observeEvent(input$btn1, {
     output$task1 <- renderPlot({
       air = airquality [, c("Ozone", "Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp")]
       f = lm.ridge (Ozone ~ ., data = air, subset = !is.na(Solar.R) & !is.na(Ozone), lambda = seq (1, 10000, by = 10))
       plot (f)
     })
   })
   observeEvent(input$btn5, {
     output$task5 <- renderPlot({
       head(longley)
       a = longley[,c("GNP.deflator","GNP", "Unemployed","Armed.Forces","Year","Employed")]
       head(a)
       length(a$GNP)
       a1 = a[1:8,]
       a2 = a[9:16,]
       l = numeric(26)
       for(i in seq (0,25)){
         l[i+1] = 10^(-3 + 0.2*i)
       }
       l
       f = lm.ridge (GNP ~ ., data = a1, subset = !is.na(GNP), lambda = l)
       plot(f)
       summary (f)
     })
   })
 }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: When you click on the button button you should see the text in the main panel, and when you click on another button, you need to clear the window. But I can`t do this

Comment: What does "I can't do this" mean? Do you have a clear question? SO is not meant to do your work if you haven't tried first and share your approach

Comment: I tried to do this many times, but it doesn`t work. I have never worked with shiny.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Diana. I've edited your question to clarify your problem. In general, you'll want to be explicit about exactly what behavior you're getting, and exactly what behavior you're expecting. "It doesn't work" is a hard question to answer. Your question could be further improved, as @NicoHaase suggests, by showing what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Make sure to use `shinyjs` too if you want...

```
library(shiny)
library(MASS)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Machine Learning"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Tasks"),
    mainPanel("Regression")
  ),
  actionButton("btn1","1"),
  actionButton("btn2","2"),
  actionButton("btn3","3"),
  actionButton("btn4","4"),
  actionButton("btn5","5"),
  actionButton("reset","Clear"),
  plotOutput("task1"),
  plotOutput("task5")
)
server <- function(input, output){

  tasks <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$btn1,{
    show("task1")
    air = airquality [, c("Ozone", "Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp")]
    f = lm.ridge (Ozone ~ ., data = air, subset = !is.na(Solar.R) & !is.na(Ozone), lambda = seq (1, 10000, by = 10))
    tasks$d1 <- f
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    hide("task1")
    hide("task5")
    tasks$d1 <- NULL
    tasks$d5 <- NULL
  })

  output$task1 <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(tasks$d1)){
      return()
    }
    plot(tasks$d1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn5,{
    show("task5")
    a = longley[,c("GNP.deflator","GNP", "Unemployed","Armed.Forces","Year","Employed")]
    head(a)
    length(a$GNP)
    a1 = a[1:8,]
    a2 = a[9:16,]
    l = numeric(26)
    for(i in seq (0,25)){
      l[i+1] = 10^(-3 + 0.2*i)
    }
    l
    f = lm.ridge (GNP ~ ., data = a1, subset = !is.na(GNP), lambda = l)
    tasks$d5 <- f
  })

  output$task5 <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(tasks$d5)){
      return()
    }
    plot(tasks$d5)
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but how to move the graph up, because when you remove 1 graph, 5 is at the bottom of the screen?